# Switch off verbose in octave for scripts

Tags: matlab, math, octave

I cannot find it anywhere, tried adding --silence, --quiet etc, but still the script prints everything on stdout as if it was the interactive mode.

I am running octave script with:

```
octave script.m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a Linux or Mac OS X machine, you could try to use the standard shell constructs to solve your problem:

```
octave script.m > /dev/null
```

will gobble everything on the standard output from your script.

**edit**
If CPU is your concern, the code you have is either badly written and would benefit from a rewrite (by adding at least semicolons after each statement) or you could try a dirty workaround.

What I'd try in that case, is shadowing the `display` function by a function that takes a single argument and doesn't do anything. If you place that function in your working directory, much output should already disappear. If that's not the case, the code might be using `fprintf` to output to the console and you could try shadowing that function. But beware that `fprintf` is also commonly used to write to files and has a more complex syntax to overload properly.

It's not the nicest thing to do, but it might yield faster results (and lots of troubles during debugging).

Comment: Yet it still does write to stdout but we only redirect the output. CPU is still wasted for that (little less ofc). Thanks